# What is the inverse of "detect", meaning "to lose sight of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm not quite looking for an antonym of "detect" (e.g., overlook) but more of the inverse action that means "lose signal" or "lose sight of".

Comment: _Elusive_ perhaps?

Comment: Since you're not failing to detect/overlooking/missing a detectable signal it seems that you're failing to maintain one that has already been detected, which, if "losing" isn't what you're after, might be a result of "ignoring" or "disregarding" it.

Comment: Need more explanation really, but perhaps *mislay*?

Comment: @PapaPoule, "losing" is what I'm going after. A signal has been detected, but when it goes out of range it is no longer detected. Wondering if there's a better word than losing.

Comment: Sorry, but can't think of any (much less better) word when talking about that kind of signal.  My "ignoring/disregarding" suggestion was based on thinking that you might be talking about other kinds of signals (of the romantic type, for example)!  Maybe if you look for other ways to say "losing altitude"/"losing control"/etc. you might hit on something. Losing altitude, for example, means "going/went down" (in the non-"romantic" way!) and you might get to "going dark/went dark" from there, but I really think that "losing it" is going to be hard to beat.

Comment: How about "miss"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the word that best fits your description is simply "[lose](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lose)":

> 11-a. To elude or outdistance: *lost their pursuers*.
>
> 11-b. To be outdistanced by: *chased the thieves but lost them*.

"We lost the signal.", "I don't want to lose sight of the captain.", "He lost the animal's silhouette on the horizon." are all clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I think [disregard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disregard) comes close to the meaning you are looking for : (from TFD)

> - to pay no attention to; leave out of consideration; ignore.

Regarding  *losing signal* ( as per your comment)  I think you can use [miss](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Miss):

> - To fail to hit, reach, catch, meet, *or otherwise make contact with*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=losing%20signal%2Cmissing%20signal%2C%20lose%20signal%2C%20miss%20signal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Closing%20signal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmissing%20signal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Close%20signal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiss%20signal%3B%2Cc0): lose signal, miss signal/losing signal, missing signal.

Comment: *Disregard* doesn’t seem right to me at all.  If you say “I disregarded the signal”, it carries a strong connotation that you *could* have paid attention to it, but did not choose to.  This is almost the opposite of what is asked for — trying to keep the signal, but being unable.  *Miss* seems also not quite right, though not so far off: “I missed the signal” suggests in most contexts that you never detected it in the first place.  In the right context it can work (“The beeping had been going all night.  Suddenly, he missed it.”) but such contexts are fairly narrow.

Comment: Disregard was my first suggestion when OP appeared  to be looking for a synonym of 'losing sight of'. OP later specified in a comment he actually was looking for a synonym of 'losing signal' which is, of course, quite different!!

Answer (score 2):

Another word for *lost* (or *lose*) here is *dropped* (or *drop*).

- *The signal was dropped.* (It is no longer detectable.)

I doubt it is much better, since it is so similar, but it is an alternative.

Comment: Not mine to accept, but that sounds to me like too good of an alternative to lose.

Comment: @PapaPoule: It's not very clear to me what the OP wants, or why. If *lose* isn't good enough then I suspect *drop* will not be good enough either. On the other hand, maybe the OP is just looking for alternatives to avoid repetition. Who knows? As is not uncommon here, the OP provides almost no context.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get your question. Did you ask for

1. Having detected a signal and then losing it.
2. Without capability to detect a signal, not due to deliberately ignoring it.

?

Therefore, I am responding with answers to both cases.

#### Case 1.

1.1

- Retaining the same capability of detecting the signal, but the signal has **faded**.
- The signal has **diminished** from our radar. It has **disappeared**.
- The signal has **[atrophied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/atrophy)**.

1.2

- The signal did not fade, but the capability of detection has **waned**.
- We **lost focus** of the signal.
- With the introduction of stealth weapons, the capability of radar has **diminished**.
- Russia is seeking to bolster their **declining** military capability.
- Our ability to detect alien warships has **[atrophied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/atrophy)**, after the Xvorkian Royal Guards enveloped our planet with a shield.

#### Case 2.

- The equipment was **oblivious** to the signal.
- We were **unaware** of the presence of any ghost.
- We were **[incognizant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incognizant)** of the imminent armada of the Japanese imperial navy upon Pearl Harbor.

Answer (score 0):

umm...  how about "undetected" or "undetectable".   E.g. when the signal goes out of range it becomes undetectable.

Comment: The question is asking for a verb. Neither of your suggestions would fit the request.

Answer (score -1):

overlook, discount, slight, miss, overpass,

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your response, as it currently stands, is not sufficiently detailed to constitute a good answer. Please elaborate. Perhaps you could give some examples as to when it would be appropriate to use each of the synonyms you have proposed. Also consider splitting your answer into multiple answers so that each one can be upvoted or downvoted individually.